# mysql_select_db returns false while mysql_error returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a database, but mysql_select_db always returns false. If I just use the first parameter of mysql_select I get the error: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'newboston', if I enter the connection link as the second parameter mysql_error returns nothing. Anyone knows what's going on?

```
<?php
$dbServer = 'localhost';
$dbUserName = 'root';
$dbPassword = 'password';

$database = 'newboston';
$db = mysqli_connect($dbServer, $dbUserName, $dbPassword);

$connectFailed = 'Could not connect to ' . $dbServer . '.';

if($db)
{
if(mysql_select_db($database, $db))
{
    echo 'Connected to ' . $database;
}

else
{
    echo 'Could not connect to ' . $database;
    die(mysql_error());
}
}

else
{
    echo $connectFailed;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`:

```
$db = mysqli_connect($dbServer, $dbUserName, $dbPassword);
```

should be:

```
$db = mysql_connect($dbServer, $dbUserName, $dbPassword);
```

(actually you should be using `mysqli` as `mysql` is deprecated).

Comment: Or, should the rest of his functions be `mysqli_*`?

Comment: Only if they change how they connect to the DB as mysqli accepts four parameters and doesn't use `mysqli_select_db()` unless you want to change databases.

Comment: You were both correct, I'm an idiot, I even read about it in some other post but was 100% certain I had removed the mysqli function.

Comment: @JohnConde: my point was not to use mysql, but you edited your post heh. user3434960: you shouldn't use mysql_* functions. Use mysqli_* at the very least, or PDO.

Comment: @HalfCrazed The solution to the problem was as I posted but the right thing to do is switch to mysqli

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing `mysqli_*` functions with `mysql_*` functions.

May I suggest learning PDO MySQL instead?